# Is it possible to have a config file that can be changed after build without having to build app again?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

One of the requirements that I was given for my app is to have a `config.json` or `config.js` file that exists outside of project directory containing settings, i.e. REST API base URL, which I will use in this example.

The REST API base URL is then imported to `axios.defaults.baseURL` and it's used in the application BUT changing the config file shouldn't require me to run `npm run build` again.

I'd normally use production ENV variables, but this still requires me to build my app again, right?

The idea is that I should:

1. Build the app for production
2. Make a script that installs whatever is needed on fresh Linux
   server and run it
3. Let a person edit the `config.js` file to setup the application however and whenever he or she wants (for example when REST API's server address changes) without having to build the application (they don't want to keep dev stuff on the server)

Is what I wrote above even possible?

Comment: Is this Vue 1.x or 2.x? One of those tags needs removing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp or something similar to trigger `npm run build` for you. Gulp has a watch function that observers and triggers.

The better option would be to require the `config.js` file in the `<head>` tag as a global variable and read the parameters within javascript. In this case your webserver will deliver the config-file everytime the page is requested.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to partially solve my issue - you can edit `appconfig.json`, save it, restart server and the settings will change without having to build it again.

What I did was I put my `appconfig.json` to `dist` folder which is where webpack-built files land, then in my `main.js` I fetch this config file with `axios` and set up the app's config.

This works, but the file has to be inside `dist` folder. If I put it elsewhere, I'm required to build my app again. I'd like it to be just outside `dist` folder, is this possible?

Comment: Please how did you do that ?